# Error while installing Scrapy for python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, failed-installation

I used **pip** to install **Scrapy** for **Python3** in **Ubuntu**

```
sudo pip3 install scrapy
```

While installing  I get this error

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/twisted/test/raiser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/twisted/test/raiser.o
    src/twisted/test/raiser.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_il8a07a/Twisted/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9935fpm4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_il8a07a/Twisted/
```

Comment: Run `apt install -y python-dev`

Comment: @TarunLalwani  Thank you its working should just use python3-dev instead of python-dev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned you were missing the dev dependencies

**For python 2**

```
sudo apt install -y python-dev
sudo pip install scrapy
```

**For python 3**

```
sudo apt install -y python3-dev
sudo pip3 install scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command

```
sudo apt install -y python3-dev
```

After that install scrapy

```
sudo pip3 install scrapy
```